# style input element to make text stick

Tags: html, css

I´m having an input element with a certain width, say 200px.
If the input text exceeds 200px, the last input is shown so that if my input text is 400px I only see the last (right) part, not the first (left). I want the first part to be shown (not the last).
"text-align: left" was my obvious choice, but it doesn´t do the trick.

How do I make my text stick to the left?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your issue, either by screenshots & code or using sites like [Codepen](http://codepen.io) or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: This would be pretty bad UX as the user would not be able to see what they were typing after the 200px mark had been reached.

Comment: You want them not to be able to see what they're typing?

Comment: Of course, they will see what they type, but when moving on to next focus, the text string will be visible from the first letter, not the last..

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" style="direction:RTL;" />
```

You can also use text-align: left;

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" style="direction:RTL; text-align:left" />
```

Give both of these a try, as they should produce similar results to what you described.

Comment: I also thought of RTL, but that produces a very ugly result with special characters (!@#$ and so on), not to mention unexpected browser "features"..

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but they do not help. The direction RTL align the text to the right, thus is the opposite to align-text: left.

My problem is when the text in the input field is longer than the field it self...

Comment: I tried to reproduce this in a fiddle without success. Then I found that the input segment itself was "moveable". As I´m on a mac I could sweep it thus orientating my text as I wanted. Would still be nice to set default presentation to left-aligned though...

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking for is a way to make it so that the caret does not lead the text, that's not possible with CSS. Maybe JavaScript, but I suspect that the browser is relying on platform-level code to perform that functionality.

This would be a fairly brutal deviation from expected behavior, but you're the designer.